# What is the best way to mock req and res of a function that passes in a client, such as a redis get function - example below

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mocking, jestjs

So I am trying to figure out the best way to mock the request and response of a function in jest, I have seen many methods, some using `jest.fn()`, others using sinon, and some using external packages.

What is the best way when wanting to return status, json, and what was requested? See the code below.

```
export const redisGet = (client) => async (req, res, next) => {
  try {

    const {
      postCode,
      houseNumber,
    } = req.params
  
    const addressObj = {
      postCode,
      houseNumber,
    }
  
    const addressGetParams = JSON.stringify(addressObj)

    await client.get(addressGetParams, (err, data) => {
      if (data) {
        return res.status(200).send({
          error: false,
          message: `Addresses found.`,
          data: JSON.parse(data)
        })
      }
      
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
          error: err,
          message: `Bad request`,
          data: JSON.parse(data),
        })
      }

      next()
    })
  } catch (e) {
    throw Error(e)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `jestjs` and `sinonjs` can mock/stub a module. Choose one of them is enough. Below an example using `jestjs`. Unit test solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
export const redisGet = (client) => async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { postCode, houseNumber } = req.params;
    const addressObj = { postCode, houseNumber };
    const addressGetParams = JSON.stringify(addressObj);

    client.get(addressGetParams, (err, data) => {
      if (data) {
        return res.status(200).send({
          error: false,
          message: `Addresses found.`,
          data: JSON.parse(data),
        });
      }

      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
          error: err,
          message: `Bad request`,
        });
      }

      next();
    });
  } catch (e) {
    throw Error(e);
  }
};
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { redisGet } from './';

describe('63253476', () => {
  it('should found addresses', async () => {
    const mClient = {
      get: jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce((params, callback) => {
        callback(null, '{"id": 1}');
      }),
    };
    const mReq = { params: { postCode: 123, houseNumber: 456 } };
    const mRes = { status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), send: jest.fn() };
    const mNext = jest.fn();
    await redisGet(mClient)(mReq, mRes, mNext);
    expect(mClient.get).toBeCalledWith(JSON.stringify({ postCode: 123, houseNumber: 456 }), expect.any(Function));
    expect(mRes.status).toBeCalledWith(200);
    expect(mRes.send).toBeCalledWith({ error: false, message: `Addresses found.`, data: { id: 1 } });
    expect(mNext).not.toBeCalled();
  });

  it('should handle error', async () => {
    const mErr = new Error('timeout');
    const mClient = {
      get: jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce((params, callback) => {
        callback(mErr);
      }),
    };
    const mReq = { params: { postCode: 123, houseNumber: 456 } };
    const mRes = { status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), send: jest.fn() };
    const mNext = jest.fn();
    await redisGet(mClient)(mReq, mRes, mNext);
    expect(mClient.get).toBeCalledWith(JSON.stringify({ postCode: 123, houseNumber: 456 }), expect.any(Function));
    expect(mRes.status).toBeCalledWith(400);
    expect(mRes.send).toBeCalledWith({ error: mErr, message: `Bad request` });
    expect(mNext).not.toBeCalled();
  });

  it('should do nothing and call next middleware', async () => {
    const mClient = {
      get: jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce((params, callback) => {
        callback();
      }),
    };
    const mReq = { params: { postCode: 123, houseNumber: 456 } };
    const mRes = { status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), send: jest.fn() };
    const mNext = jest.fn();
    await redisGet(mClient)(mReq, mRes, mNext);
    expect(mClient.get).toBeCalledWith(JSON.stringify({ postCode: 123, houseNumber: 456 }), expect.any(Function));
    expect(mRes.status).not.toBeCalled();
    expect(mRes.send).not.toBeCalled();
    expect(mNext).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/63253476/index.test.ts (11.338s)
  63253476
    ✓ should found addresses (8ms)
    ✓ should handle error (2ms)
    ✓ should do nothing and call next middleware (2ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |    92.86 |      100 |      100 |    91.67 |                   |
 index.ts |    92.86 |      100 |      100 |    91.67 |                26 |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.824s
```